# How to solve Avoided redundant navigation to current location error in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I am new in vue and i got the error after user logged in and redirect to another route.
Basically i am a PHP developer and i use laravel with vue. Please help me to solve this error.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/admin".

Here is the screenshot too

[image]

**Vue Code**

```
 methods: {
        loginUser() {
            var data = {
                email: this.userData.email,
                password: this.userData.password
            };
            this.app.req.post("api/auth/authenticate", data).then(res => {
                const token = res.data.token;
                sessionStorage.setItem("chatbot_token", token);
                this.$router.push("/admin");
            });
        }
    }
```

**Vue Routes**

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/admin",
        component: Navbar,
        name: "navbar",
        meta: {
            authGuard: true
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                component: Dashboard,
                name: "dashboard"
            },
            {
                path: "users",
                component: Users,
                name: "user"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "/login",
        component: Login,
        name: "login"
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: "history"
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const loggedInUserDetail = !!sessionStorage.getItem("chatbot_token");
    if (to.matched.some(m => m.meta.authGuard) && !loggedInUserDetail)
        next({ name: "login" });
    else next();
});
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

As I remember well, you can use catch clause after this.$router.push. Then it will look like:

```
this.$router.push("/admin").catch(()=>{});
```

This allows you to only avoid the error displaying, because browser thinks the exception was handled.

Comment: This can be extended to `if (this.$route.name !== 'navbar') this.$router.push("/admin").catch(()=>{});`

Comment: that don't solve problem, only avoid display any problem to change route

Comment: If this was the only possible meaningful error that could arise from calling `push()` then sure... but that's not the case so you'll suppress every error message coming from there. This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: great!! tnks so much

Comment: it's wrong answer as it doesn't solve the problem it hides as @EmilianoPamont has told.

Comment: This is terrible advice, please ignore this answer. @adonis had the good one.

Comment: Actually, this problem is caused because you are redirecting to the page you are currently on. The comment from @IVOGELOV is correct to not display the error, but sometimes there is a problem where the link path is correct but the display is not correct. You can use catch and force the browser to refresh the page.

`this.$router.push("/admin").catch(()=>{this.$forceUpdate(});`

*not tested yet

Comment: An easier way to go about it is to await the router.push because navigations are asynchronous. So it would look like `await this.$router.push("/admin")`

Answer (score 58):

I don't think suppressing all errors from router is good practice, I made just picks of certain errors, like this:

```js
router.push(route).catch(err => {
    // Ignore the vuex err regarding  navigating to the page they are already on.
    if (
      err.name !== 'NavigationDuplicated' &&
      !err.message.includes('Avoided redundant navigation to current location')
    ) {
      // But print any other errors to the console
      logError(err);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 33):

Maybe this is happening because your are trying to route to the existing `$route.matched.path`.

### For original-poster

You may want to prevent the error by preventing a route to the same path:

```js
if (this.$route.path != '/admin') {
    this.$router.push("/admin");
}
```

### Generic solutions

You could create a method to check for this if you are sending dynamic routes, using one of several options

1. **Easy**: Ignore the error
2. **Hard**: Compare the `$route.matched` against the desired route

#### 1. Ignore the error

You can catch the `NavigationDuplicated` exception and ignore it.

```js
pushRouteTo(route) {
    try {
        this.$router.push(route);
    } catch (error) {
       if (!(error instanceof NavigationDuplicated)) {
           throw error;
       }
    }
}
```

Although this is much simpler, it bothers me because it generates an exception.

#### 2. Compare the `$route.matched` against the desired route

You can compare the `$route.matched` against the desired route

```js
pushRouteTo(route) {
    // if sending path:
    if (typeof(route) == "string") {
        if (this.$route.path != route) {
            this.$router.push(route);
        }
    } else { // if sending a {name: '', ...}
        if (this.$route.name == route.name) {
            if ('params' in route) {
                let routesMatched = true;
                for (key in this.$route.params) {
                    const value = this.$route.params[key];
                    if (value == null || value == undefined) {
                        if (key in route.params) {
                            if (route.params[key] != undefined && route.params[key] != null) {
                                routesMatched = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (key in route.params) {
                            if (routes.params[key] != value) {
                                routesMatched = false;
                                break
                            }
                        } else {
                            routesMatched = false;
                            break

                        }
                    }
                    if (!routesMatched) {
                        this.$router.push(route);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Object.keys(this.$route.params).length != 0) {
                    this.$router.push(route);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously a lot longer but doesn't throw an error. Choose your poison.

### Runnable demo

You can try both implementations in this demo:

```js
const App = {
  methods: {
    goToPageCatchException(route) {
      try {
        this.$router.push(route)
      } catch (error) {
        if (!(error instanceof NavigationDuplicated)) {
          throw error;
        }
      }
    },
    goToPageMatch(route) {
    if (typeof(route) == "string") {
        if (this.$route.path != route) {
            this.$router.push(route);
        }
    } else { // if sending a {name: '', ...}
        if (this.$route.name == route.name) {
            if ('params' in route) {
                let routesMatched = true;
                for (key in this.$route.params) {
                    const value = this.$route.params[key];
                    if (value == null || value == undefined) {
                        if (key in route.params) {
                            if (route.params[key] != undefined && route.params[key] != null) {
                                routesMatched = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (key in route.params) {
                            if (routes.params[key] != value) {
                                routesMatched = false;
                                break
                            }
                        } else {
                            routesMatched = false;
                            break

                        }
                    }
                    if (!routesMatched) {
                        this.$router.push(route);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Object.keys(this.$route.params).length != 0) {
                    this.$router.push(route);
                }
            }
        } else {
          this.$router.push(route);
        }
    }
    },
  },
  template: `
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar bg-light">
          <a href="#" @click.prevent="goToPageCatchException({name:'page1'})">Catch Exception</a>
          <a href="#" @click.prevent="goToPageMatch({name:'page2'})">Match Route</a>
    </nav>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>`
}
const Page1 = {template: `
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Catch Exception</h1>
    <p>We used a try/catch to get here</p>
  </div>`
}
const Page2 = {template: `
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Match Route</h1>
    <p>We used a route match to get here</p>
  </div>`
}

const routes = [
  { name: 'page1', path: '/', component: Page1 },
  { name: 'page2', path: '/page2', component: Page2 },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: You can compare the full path with the router resolver used as `this.$router.resolve(params).route.fullPath`. That will give you full path with query params back where you then compare with === against the current `this.$route.fullPath`.

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution by adding the following code to `router.js`:

```js
import router from 'vue-router'; 

const originalPush = router.prototype.push
router.prototype.push = function push(location) {
  return originalPush.call(this, location).catch(err => err)
}
```

Comment: Thank You your this piece of code solve my issue

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion. Thank you after 2 years and 7 months haha

Answer (score 11):

Just to make this complete you can also compare the `from` and `to` route fullPaths and compare them against each other which seems to me a simple, valid and reusable solution.

Here is an example in a component method:

```js
 move(params){
    // get comparable fullPaths
    let from  = this.$route.fullPath
    let to    = this.$router.resolve(params).route.fullPath

    if(from === to) { 
        // handle any error due the redundant navigation here
        // or handle any other param modification and route afterwards
        return 
    }

    // route as expected
    this.$router.push(params)
}
```

If you wanna use that you just put your route params in it like `this.move({ name: 'something' })`. This is the easiest way to handle the duplicate route without running into try catch syntax. And also you can have that method exported in `Vue.prorotype.$move = ...` which will work across the whole application.

Comment: Thank you. This solution is simple and fixed my issue.

Answer (score 7):

Provide a Typescript solution

The idea is to overwrite the `router.push` function. You can handle (ignore) the error in one place, instead of writing `catch` everywhere to handle it.

This is the function to overwrite

```ts
export declare class VueRouter {
  // ...
  push(
    location: RawLocation,
    onComplete?: Function,
    onAbort?: ErrorHandler
  ): void
}
```

Here is the code

```ts
// in router/index.ts

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter, { RawLocation, Route } from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const originalPush = VueRouter.prototype.push;
VueRouter.prototype.push = function push(location: RawLocation): Promise<Route> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    originalPush.call(this, location, () => {
      // on complete

      resolve(this.currentRoute);
    }, (error) => {
      // on abort

      // only ignore NavigationDuplicated error
      if (error.name === 'NavigationDuplicated') {
        resolve(this.currentRoute);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
};

// your router configs ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Vue is all the better for having people able to provide Typescript examples!

Comment: Excellent solution, though the check for whether to ignore the error should probably be `error.name === 'NavigationDuplicated' || error.message.includes('Avoided redundant navigation to current location') ` . Checking for the error name wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 5):

you can define and use a function like this:

```js
routerPush(path) {
  if (this.$route.path !== path) {
    this.$router.push(path);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is this not built-in?? Should be default behavior and then there could be force push option.

Answer (score 3):

### Global solution

In `router/index.js`, after initialization

```js
// init or import router..


/* ... your routes ... */


// error handler
const onError = (e) => {
  // avoid NavigationDuplicated
  if (e.name !== 'NavigationDuplicated') throw e
}

// keep original function
const _push = router.__proto__.push
// then override it
router.__proto__.push = function push (...args) {
  try {
    const op = _push.call(this, ...args)
    if (op instanceof Promise) op.catch(onError)
    return op
  } catch (e) {   
    onError(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It means - you want to navigate to a route that looks the same as the current one and Vue doesn’t want to trigger everything again.

```
 methods: {
    loginUser() {
        var data = {
            email: this.userData.email,
            password: this.userData.password
        };
        this.app.req.post("api/auth/authenticate", data).then(res => {
            const token = res.data.token;
            sessionStorage.setItem("chatbot_token", token);
            // Here you conditioally navigate to admin page to prevent error raised
            if(this.$route.name !== "/admin") {
              this.$router.push("/admin");
            }
            
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Clean solution ;)

Move the code to an util function. So you can replace all `this.$router.push` with it.

```js
import router from '../router'; // path to the file where you defined 
                                // your router

const goToRoute = (path) => 
    if(router.currentRoute.fullPath !== path) router.push(path);

export {
    goToRoute
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above mentioned solutions: a convenient way is to put this snippet in main.js to make it a global function

```
Vue.mixin({
    /**
     * Avoids redundand error when navigating to already active page
     */
    routerPush(route) {
      this.$router.push(route).catch((error) => {
        if(error.name != "NavigationDuplicated") {
          throw error;
        }
      })
    },
})
```

Now you can call in any component:

```
this.routerPush('/myRoute')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added the code below in the `main.js` file of my project and the error disappeared.

```
import Router from 'vue-router'
const routerPush = Router.prototype.push
Router.prototype.push = function push(location) {
return routerPush.call(this, location).catch(error => error)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue and when I looked for a solution I found `.catch(() => {})` which is actually telling the browser that we have handled the error please don’t print the error in dev tools :) Hehehe Nice hack! but ignoring an error is not a solution I think. So what I did, I created a utility function that takes two parameters `router, path`, and compares it with the current route's path if both are the same it means we already on that route and it ignore the route change. So simple :)

Here is the code.

```
export function checkCurrentRouteAndRedirect(router, path) {
  const {
    currentRoute: { path: curPath }
  } = router;
  if (curPath !== path) router.push({ path });
}

checkCurrentRouteAndRedirect(this.$router, "/dashboard-1");
checkCurrentRouteAndRedirect(this.$router, "/dashboard-2");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and i solve it like that.

by adding that in my router file

import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

```
const originalPush = Router.prototype.push 
Router.prototype.push = function push(location) {
   return originalPush.call(this, location).catch(err => err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short solution:

```
  if (this.$router.currentRoute.name !== 'routeName1') {
    this.$router.push({
      name: 'routeName2',
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but trying to add my 10 cents. Most of the answers- including the one which is accepted are trying to hide the exception without finding the root cause which causes the error. I did have the same issue in our project and had a feeling it's something to do with Vue/ Vue router. In the end I managed to prove myself wrong and it was due to a code segment we had in App.vue to replace the route in addition to the similar logic like you in the index.ts.

```
this.$router.replace({ name: 'Login' })
```

So try to do a search and find if you are having any code which calls $router.replace OR $router.push for the route you are worried about- "/admin". Simply your code must be calling the route more than once, not the Vue magically trying to call it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why they no longer handle this case internally, but this is what I have implemented in our app.

If you are already on the fullPath then dont bother pushing / replacing

```
const origPush = Router.prototype.push;
Router.prototype.push = function(to) {
  const match = this.matcher.match(to);
  // console.log(match.fullPath, match)
  if (match.fullPath !== this.currentRoute.fullPath) {
    origPush.call(this, to);
  } else {
    // console.log('Already at route', match.fullPath);
  }
}

const origReplace = Router.prototype.replace;
Router.prototype.replace = function(to) {
  const match = this.matcher.match(to);
  // console.log(match.fullPath, match)
  if (match.fullPath !== this.currentRoute.fullPath) {
    origReplace.call(this, to);
  } else {
    // console.log('Already at route', match.fullPath);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answer comes in super late. Instead of catching the error I looked for a way to prevent the error the come up. Therefore I've enhanced the router by an additional function called `pushSave`. Probably this can be done via navGuards as well

```js
VueRouter.prototype.pushSave = function(routeObject) {
  let isSameRoute = true

  if (this.currentRoute.name === routeObject.name && routeObject.params) {
    for (const key in routeObject.params) {
      if (
        !this.currentRoute.params[key] ||
        this.currentRoute.params[key] !== routeObject.params[key]
      ) {
        isSameRoute = false
      }
    }
  } else {
    isSameRoute = false
  }

  if (!isSameRoute) {
    this.push(routeObject)
  }
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})
```

As you've probably realized this will only work if you provide a routeObject like

```js
this.$router.pushSave({ name: 'MyRoute', params: { id: 1 } })
```

So you might need to enhance it to work for strings aswell

Answer (score 0):

1. For components `<router-link>`
   You can create a new component instead of `<router-link>`.

Component name: `<to-link>`

```
<template>
  <router-link :to="to" :event="to === $route.path || loading ? '' : 'click'" :class="classNames">
    <slot></slot>
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ToLink',
  props: {
    to: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: ''
    },
    classNames: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

For bind:

```
import ToLink from '@/components/to-link'
Vue.component('to-link', ToLink)
```

2. For `$router.push()` need create global method.

```
toHttpParams(obj) {
    let str = ''
    for (const key in obj) {
      if (str !== '') {
        str += '&'
      }
      str += key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key])
    }
    return str
  },
  async routerPush(path, queryParams = undefined, params = undefined, locale = true) {
    let fullPath = this.$route.fullPath
    if (!path) {
      path = this.$route.path
    }
    if (!params) {
      params = this.$route.params
    }
    if (queryParams && typeof queryParams === 'object' && Object.entries(queryParams).length) {
      path = path + '?' + this.toHttpParams(queryParams)
    }
   
    if (path !== fullPath) {
      const route = { path, params, query: queryParams }
      await this.$router.push(route)
    }
  }
```