# how solve Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/login". in vue?

Tags: vue.js

Hi everybody i'm trying to make login page and redirect to home page ('/')

When i'm logging i haven't errors in console i can see the error using vue devtools

**ERROR VUE DEV TOOL**

```
End of navigation
/login
02:27:19.124
guard:afterEach
failure:Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/login".
status:❌
from:/login
fullPath:"/login"
path:"/login"
query:Object (empty)
hash:""
name:"login"
params:Object (empty)
matched:Array[1]
meta:Object (empty)
redirectedFrom:undefined
href:"/login"
to:/login
fullPath:"/login"
hash:""
query:Object (empty)
name:"login"
path:"/login"
params:Object (empty)
matched:Array[1]
meta:Object (empty)
redirectedFrom:Object
href:"/login"
```

this is my login's method

```
methods:{
        async submitForm(user){
        const userForm=new FormData();
        userForm.append("username", this.username);
        userForm.append("password", this.password);
        await this.$store.dispatch("auth/login", userForm).then( 
            ()=>{
                const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
                console.log(user) //to check if i logged, in console get undefined but if try localStorage.getItem('user') i got the user.
                this.$router.push('/')
                }),
            (error)=>{
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

**ROUTES**

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { top: 0 }
  },
  routes,
})
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'dashboard',
    component: () => import('@/views/Dashboard.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'home',
        component: () => import('@/views/dashboard/Home.vue'),
      },
....
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const publicPages = ['/login'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');

  // trying to access a restricted page + not logged in
  // redirect to login page
  if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
    next('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

**auth.service**

```
class AuthService {
  login(user) {
    let dator={
      access_token: '',
      user:{}
    }
    console.log('AUTHSERVICE-->\n'+user)
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + 'login/access-token', user)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.access_token)
        if (response.data.access_token) {
          dator.access_token=response.data.access_token
          localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(dator.access_token))
          axios.get(API_URL + 'users/me/', { headers: authHeader() })
            .then(response =>{
              localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data))
              dator.user=response.data
            })
        }
        return dator;
      });
  }
```

**auth.module VUEX**

```
import AuthService from '../services/auth.service';
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const initialState = token && user
  ? { status: { loggedIn: true }, token,user }
  : { status: { loggedIn: false }, token:null, user: null };

export const auth = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState,
  actions: {
    login({ commit }, userForm) {
        console.log(userForm)
      return AuthService.login(userForm).then(
        datologin => {
          console.log('datologin',datologin)
          commit('loginSuccess', datologin);
          return Promise.resolve(datologin);
        },
        error => {
          commit('loginFailure');
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    },
```

if after login i force the '/' in the browser the page work. So i don't know where is my bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Avoided redundant navigation to current location error in vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62462276/how-to-solve-avoided-redundant-navigation-to-current-location-error-in-vue)

Comment: yes i tried but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for noob error. The problem was in second request with axios so i refactor this part and now work

```
async asyncLogin(user){
    let uservuex={
      access_token: '',
      user:{}
    }
    try{
      const token = await axios.post(API_URL + 'login/access-token', user)
      uservuex.access_token = await token.data.access_token
      localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(uservuex.access_token))
      const me = await axios.get(API_URL + 'users/me/', { headers: authHeader() })
      uservuex.user= await me.data
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(uservuex.user))
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }

    return uservuex
  }
```